# how to fix my increasing validation loss and decreasing training loss?

Tags: lstm, accuracy, validation

here is the code that got me this, please i need an advise on what to do to correct this.

```
#import necessary libraries

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np

# Split the data into training and testing sets
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(bot_df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Tokenize and pad the sequences
max_words = total_unique_words
max_len = 100
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_df['cleaned_description'])
X_train_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_df['cleaned_description'])
X_test_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_df['cleaned_description'])
X_train_pad = pad_sequences(X_train_seq, maxlen=max_len)
X_test_pad = pad_sequences(X_test_seq, maxlen=max_len)

# Initialize the label encoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

# Retrieve class names
class_names = label_encoder.classes_

# Fit and transform labels in the training set
y_train_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(train_df['price_category'])

# Transform labels in the test set
y_test_encoded = label_encoder.transform(test_df['price_category'])

# Build the model
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(Embedding(input_dim=max_words, output_dim=128, input_length=max_len))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(100))
lstm_model.add(Dense(len(class_names), activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
lstm_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
history = lstm_model.fit(X_train_pad, y_train_encoded, epochs=5, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

# Evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = lstm_model.evaluate(X_test_pad, y_test_encoded)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {accuracy}")

# Plot training and validation accuracy
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend()

# Plot training and validation loss curve for the model
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: lstm training curve]

Comment: Hi , welcome to the site. It seems you are heavily overfitting. Start specifying a learning rate with small values (replace `'adam'` with `keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)`. If that does not work, reduce the dimensionality of everything. Also, check other answers in this site about overfitting. After trying stuff, comment here and let us know how it went.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with noe that the model is overfitting. Try adjusting the hyperparameters. Reduce the learning rate, try more epochs. You can also try using a dropout layer. Is it possible that your dataset is very small?

Answer (score 0):

I see the max_len is 100 as your input length and then have 100 neurons in the LSTM layer. I'd suggest maybe 20 to 50 neurons instead as you are assigning 1 whole neuron per input. Also dropout layers and L1/L2 regularisers may help reduce the "complexity" of the model that may be present.